# Set include_path and auto_prepend_file with rack-legacy

Tags: php, rack-pow

I am using [rack-legacy](https://github.com/eric1234/rack-legacy) to run a PHP app under [pow](http://pow.cx/), as described [here](http://stuff-things.net/2011/05/16/legacy-development-with-pow/).

Now rack-legacy does not parse `.htaccess` and I wonder how I can set `include_path` and `auto_prepend_file` so all scripts include my standard lib.